# jquery validate and IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi i am using jquery validate that works fine in FF but IE dont listen the rules and dont submit.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("form#loginForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form){
                customer_dispatch('login');
            },
            rules: {
                user_login: { required: true },
                user_password: { required: true },                              
            },
            messages: { }   
        });
```

})

AND THE FORM

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="login-table">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td width="50%" class="login">
            <h2 class="subheader">Είσοδος Χρήστη</h2>

        <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" id="do" name="do" size="10" value="login" />
        <div id="form_container" >
        <ul>
            <li id="li_1" >
                    <label class="description" for="lastLabel">Όνομα Χρήστη :</label>
                    <input id="user_login" name="user_login" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
            </li>       
            <li id="li_2" >
                    <label class="description" for="lastLabel">Κωδικός :</label>
                    <input id="user_password" name="user_password" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/>   
            </li>   
        </ul>
        </div><!--form_container-->

        <div class="clear">
            <div class="buttons-container right">               
                <span  class="button-submit-action"><input class="hand" type="submit" value="Sign in" /></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        </form>

    </td><!--form login-->
```

IN FF works perfect. I am using the jquery and validate file from the demo.When running the demo works in IE.

Am i missimg somethig
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the trailing comma here :

```
user_password: { required: true },
```

Remove that and it should work.

Comment: He asked if he was *missing* something. Your answer only applies if he has something *overrun* ;) +1 for the spot on nevertheless.

Comment: YES IT IS. Thank for your reply, you saved mu life

Comment: No probs :) I've done it loads of times, that's why i was quick to spot it :p

Comment: This occurs a lot because languages like c# let you use the comma in a structure like this.